# Best storage file for existing images which is writeable in Android

Tags: android, file, storage, assets

I have a database which contains Image paths. I have access to the existing Images by these database paths.

I also need a folder containing Images which are writeable to modify the images.
Besides "assets" files are only readable, so I can't change them. Therefore the "assets" folder doesn't work for me.

What is the best file storage in this case?

My solution was to save images in assets and then copy the folder in an internal storage, but it takes a large amount of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to save the files in internal or external android device.